# AWS Lambda Function how to disable Actions Export/DeleteFunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Wanted to know how to disable Actions Export/Delete Function for a lambda function

Objective: Want to restrict end users from accessing  lambda code which is deployed in end users environment.

After publishing the function in the end userenvironment the user can export function to download the sam file and lambda function code and wanted to restrict it.

Thanks
Nataraj

Comment: IAM Actions and Conditions are available on: [Actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS Lambda - Service Authorization Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_awslambda.html). I can see several `Delete*` actions, but none that reference Export. You can use these actions in IAM Policies to grant/restrict access to certain Actions. If you wan to be more specific about _which_ functions they can access, look for Actions that include a Condition that lets you restrict by function.

Comment: Thank you for your response John
The environment that i am working is that Nodejs code would be deployed in a client cloud account and we do not want somebody to download the code

Comment: I suspect that it would be extremely difficult to 'protect' Lambda function code from being accessed. The only true way of doing that would be to run it in a different AWS Account and grant cross-account permissions for it to be run from another Account.